# How to prove $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(a_k)\leq nf\left(\frac{b}{n}\right) $ for sufficiently large $ n $ here?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

> Let $ 0<a<b $, $ f\in C^1[a,b] $. Assume that $ f $ is concave on $ [0,a] $ and convex on $ [a,b] $ with $ f'(0)>f'(b) $. Please prove that there exist $ n_0\in\mathbb{Z} $ which is sufficiently large, such that for any $ n\geq n_0 $ and $ a_1+a_2+...+a_n=b $ with $ a_i\geq 0 $($ i=1,2,...,n $), we have $ \sum_{k=1}^nf(a_i)\leq nf\left(\frac{b}{n}\right) $.

Simple observation shows that if $ a_i\in [0,a] $ for all $ i $, the result is easy to prove. However, I cannot deal with the situation that there exists some $ i_0 $ such that $ a_{i_0}\in(0,b] $. I guess that such case is related with the statement that $ f'(0)>f'(b) $, but I do not know how to continue the proof. Could you give me some references or hints?

Comment: See https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1186/1029-242X-2011-101.pdf .Hope you find something interesting .:-)